# Populating a WPF treeview with a list with nested lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I got the following setup in my application;

5 datatypes;

- Area
- System
- Equipment
- Device
- Signal

Now, Area is always the highest level, but can contain chidren of all the other four types - so I've added a list of Areas, and under each area there will be a nested list of the other types.

A system will always be a children of an Area, but can contain children of the last three types - and so on.

[See my nested layout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H9Yq.png)

Now I want to populate a treeview with this nested layout. I've already made a list of areas with nested lists with the other types - but how do I get a treeview to show this hierarchy?

Comment: Do they absolutely need to be different types? If you could translate whatever data you had into a generic type. Call that Parent. That could then have a List of Parent as  Children.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate) and [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate).
Because your TreeView is supposed to support multiple different Templates you should place them is the resources of the TreeView.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionWithRootElement}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type blabla:Area}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItemsCollectionOfThisType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Area Type" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type blabla:System}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItemsCollectionOfThisType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="System Type" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type blabla:Signal}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Signal Type" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

A few things to note:

- The TreeView need a Collection to bind to, if there is only one Area you might need to create a collection with only one Area element.
- HierarchicalDataTemplate has children, DataTemplate does not. Any class with nested collections is therefore represented by an HierarchicalDataTemplate. The 'Leaf' elements which have no further children are represented by DataTemplate.
- The XAML above uses the dummy namespace blabla. You have to adjust it to fit you needs e.g. `<Window xmlns:blabla="clr-namespace:MyApp.Namespace"></Window>`